# Which upload method is preferable when hosting the files in the server

Tags: php, server

Which upload method is preferable ? Individual file upload through FTP or zip file upload through file manager.

Do any file lost while using zip file upload?

Answer (score 1):

Uploading a zip file can be faster as the total size you'll transfer will be smaller; Just think that you'll have to unzip you file after the transfer.
And if you zipped all your filed correctly, nothing will be lost.

Comment: i faced the problem when uploading the wordpress file. My code is worked very fine in demo server and the problem was trying to upload zip file in another server.

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot quicker to upload a zipped file and extract it on the server. If only FTP could support remote unzipping.

If it's a large file, I tend to upload the .zip via FTP and then extract it via cPanel.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, do Zip File upload via FTP.
First of all, text files is good compressed so you save on the size that needs to be uploaded to server.
When moving separate files via FTP there usually is separate connection to server for each file, so it will be very slow.
Also, if you can, don't use File Manager that mostly all host providers offers, because moving files via browser has 30s timeout (unless it's increased, but still not recommended). Only use it if there is no other possibility to extract Zip files via FTP. But still, it will take some time to upload big files.